# if 関数の方法 discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!set on') {
    const reply = 2
    msg.channel.send('on設定しました')
  }  if (msg.content === '!set off') {
    const reply = 1
    msg.channel.send('off設定しました')
  }
})

client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (reply = 1) {
    return;
  } else if (reply = 2) {
    if(msg.content.match('こんに|こんちゃ')){
      msg.channel.send('こんにちは～(^▽^)/')
    }
  }
  })
```

これでやるとonにしても反応せず、offでも反応しません。どうしたらいいですか？

Answer (score 0):

discord.js v13だとmessageのことを、msgにできます。

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
  if (msg.content === '!set on') {
    const reply = 2
    msg.channel.send('on設定しました')
  }  if (msg.content === '!set off') {
    const reply = 1
    msg.channel.send('off設定しました')
  }
})

client.on('messageCreate', async msg => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (reply = 1) {
    return;
  } else if (reply = 2) {
    if(msg.content.match('こんにちは')){
      msg.channel.send('こんにちは')
    }
  }
  })
```

ONの場合は応答し、OFFの場合は何もしないようにするには以下のようにしてください。

```js
const data = new Map()

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content === "!set-on") {
    data.set('返答' , 'ON')
    await message.channel.send("onに設定しました。")
  }
  if (message.content === "!set-off") {
    data.set('返答' , 'OFF') 
    await message.channel.send("offに設定しました。")
  }
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (data.has('返答')) {
    if(data.get('返答') === 'ON')
    if (message.content === "こんにちは") {
        message.channel.send('こんにちは')
      }
    }
  }
);
```